# cx_Freeze with RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build an execution file from a directory containing a set of Python [Dash Plotly](https://dash.plotly.com/) files. To achieve this, I've used the Python package [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). However, after running the command below

```
python setup.py build
```

I've got the following error

[image]

It looks like that this error comes from Python package itself. Does anyone have experiences with this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of my projects. I discovered that in the build process, cx_Freeze was taking all the packages installed in the computer, so I sat up a virtual-environment on the root directory of the project to install there only the packages needed for my project, once this was done cx_Freeze chose only the packages in the venv, and the error disappeared.

I found out about this in the [common error section of the cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html).